# Boss watched me do anonymous survey, treats me different now

Tags: management, bullying

My boss was continuously walking past me as I was filling in an anonymous survey, she saw me put a negative comment in about the workplace itself. All day after that she seemed to be picking on me continuously, telling me that I was not doing anything properly or quickly enough. She then asked me why I put in the negative comment and seemed really angry with me for the rest of the day. Is that breaking confidentiality policy? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere could even make things worse, first negative statement about the workplace, then complaining about the manager.....

Comment: It's not an "anonymous survey" if you fill it out while your boss is shoulder surfting. Next time, make sure you fill it out when you're alone.

Comment: I wonder if her bonus was tied to your response...

Comment: Your boss is looking at you while you're supposed to be filling an "anonymous survey"? And she asks why you put in a negative comment?!

Comment: @Erik There are no anonymous surveys in companies, unless they are done on paper and put into a box.

Comment: @daraos I don't see why you would treat those done on paper differently. They suffer all the same potential problems that digital ones do.

Comment: @Erik on paper, you can only try to recognize someone's handwriting or looking for hints in the content. It's a lot of work for HR, and they need help from managers. With web-surveys, they know who filled it out right away, and crunch numbers.

Comment: That's only if assuming malicious intent, which you can also easily have on paper. You just need to subtly mark each survey before you hand it out. If a company is intentionally giving out non-anonymous anonymous surveys, that sounds like a good reason to brush up your resumé.

Answer (score 9):

> She then asked me why I put in the negative comment and seemed really
>   angry with me for the rest of the day. Is that breaking
>   confidentiality policy?

It may, but thats not really relevant there. The incident happened and now there is a loss of trust between you and your manager. You can try to amend this by working with her and adressing concerns directly, which may work if she is the kind of person to accept that.

You could also complain to HR, and they may even do something, but realize that in a whole lot of companies, doing that will not only net you nothing but put you on the list to be sacked at the earliest next convenience. It sucks and its unfair, but thats what it is.

About anonymous surveys: They're rarely effective, mainly because most people will (rightly or wrongly) assume that they're not really anonymous, and often thats true. As for your case, if you plan on answering anonymous surveys in the future, make sure you're alone and make sure to formulate any complaints you may have in such a way that its not obvious who wrote them.

Ultimately, if your manager is not receptive to mending the bridge you inadvertenly burned with her, it may be best to cut your losses and start looking for a new job.

Comment: Side note on HR: their job is to manage the human **resources** for the organization.  At the end of the day, their biggest concern will always be protecting the organization from liability.  They aren't the schoolteacher and they won't scold the bully.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion because I don't know the personality of your boss, but depending on the nature of the negative comment, you could always bring it out in the open, and try to work with your boss to tackle the issue.

OK she knows you think this, you know she knows, so there's no point in pretending it's anonymous any more. Why not discuss it openly with her and see if there's anything that can be done about it?

If the situation allows (as in you're confident she won't freak out) you could also mention how you feel about her treatment of you and her invasion of your privacy - after all what was the point of the survey if responders aren't free to give their honest opinion privately?

Answer (score 1):

First and most important question: What does "boss" mean? Team leader? Manager? CEO? Company owner? Anyone but the company owner has to play by the company's rules.

Looking over your shoulder while you fill out an anonymous survey is obviously bad, and threatening because of your answers is really bad. Well, unless your "boss" is the company owner, you'll have to figure out whether this behaviour is accepted in your company or not. First you'd check what the official position of your company is. If the company's official position is "you are nothing and your boss does whatever she wants", there is nothing you can do. If the company's official position is "this survey is anonymous, we don't accept any breach of anonymity, and we don't accept any retaliation over complaints in the survey", then find out *carefully* what their real position is.

Answer (score -1):

Putting something negative on the survey was a big mistake. These things are never anonymous, at some point someone reads them.

What you can do is watch your back, you have hurt someone, expect retaliation. Unless they overtly say they're targeting you because of what you put on the survey, AND you can prove that, then there is not much else you can do.

So weather the storm until it dies down and goes back to normal, and don't make that mistake again.

Comment: Yes, some places are crap, but the attitude displayed in this answer sounds extremely wearying and counterproductive: never try and improve your workplace, never trust anyone, expect everyone to be vindicative, and try your best not to enjoy your job?

Comment: I have to disagree with the downvotes here, Kilisi is right. In a whole lot of workplaces, honesty in this case is a huge liability. If your workplace laws allow for it, you have to expect and plan for the worst.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the aggresiveness of this answer but Kilisi does make a good point - at best you can't be sure if it's OK to be honest on it unless your company and management have a good record for responding to criticism.

Comment: @Ben With all due respect, workplaces which *could* be improved don't need to use *anonymous* surveys for it.

Comment: A fair point @Masked; however, that doesn't take into account that some people are uncomfortable standing up in public or raising issues with line mangers etc.. A good business would take everyone's communication preferences into account and allow people to contribute to the betterment of the group anonymously as well as via more public methodologies. This is often the reason for whistleblower lines as well.

Comment: @Ben Hmm, that's a good point. However, I still don't see much wrong with this answer. Kilisi is blunt, but he is right. Even if anonymous surveys are "genuinely" anonymous, it is always possible to guess who said what.

Comment: For example, I once conducted a week long training session for about 100 colleagues (in 5 batches), and asked them for anonymous feedback at the end.About 25 people actually filled up the form, but I could still tell who said what, and this was despite the fact that I had not known most of them before this training session. Of course, I did not hold any grudge against anyone, but you cannot be sure that everyone who reads anonymous feedback would do the same.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes there isn't much you can do after someone has an opinion.  The best you can probably do is either talk to your manager and clear things up with her.  Explain why you put the negative comment down and have a conversion with her on what she expects from you.  Or your second option is to find a new position in another department or with another company.

Answer (score -2):

Have you been forced to fill out the form in front of your boss? If no, you should take better care next time.

Also anonymous is relative, usually feedback gets back to the persons mentioned and if you voiced your concerns earlier they can guess who it came from.

But the way your boss is acting is really unprofessional, try to get rid of her somehow or consider changing jobs, would not want to work with such a person for a longer period of time.

Comment: depends how much of a psychopath he is! :) just kidding, nothing illegal, but if there is a way to complain about the boss and get him fired or if you can get him promoted away for great work that might solve the problem. otherwise i recommend not working there longer than needed-

Answer (score -5):

I think you should write a memo containing some version of the following and send copies to your boss and to HR.

> Your employees know a hell of a lot more about what's going on in your
>   establishment than you ever will. You can glean a great deal of useful
>   information from them if you can get them to talk to you. But -- will
>   they respond honestly, or will they tell you what they think you want
>   to hear?
>
> It’s hard to be completely candid with someone if that person has the
>   ability to fire you or make your life miserable. Anonymous surveys are
>   *anonymous* so that respondents can provide honest and candid information without worrying about negative consequences. If you want
>   to develop trust among your employees, an anonymous survey conveys
>   that you respect their privacy and value their input, even on
>   sensitive or unpopular topics.
>
> Seeking out the bearer of negative news destroys this trust, and
>   insures that the contents of your anonymous surveys will be worthless.
>   When you break the promise of anonymity, you demonstrate that you are
>   fundamentally dishonest. Your employees are not fools; they soon learn
>   that you are not to be trusted. The best ones will leave, and the rest
>   will start lying to protect themselves.
>
> And you still won't know what's going on in your establishment.

You might want to change the tone to suit your boss's auricular, but don't lose the main message: violating a promise of anonymity is a foolish and *counterproductive* betrayal of trust.